# Nutch How to avoid crawl calendar webpage generated by CGI

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch to crawl a large website.

The webpages are generated by CGI program. Most of the webpages' URL contains expressions such as `?id=2323&title=foo`.

I want to crawl these webpages as they contain many useful information.

However, a problem I'm facing is that this website has a calendar. Some date-like webpages are generated too. That means Nutch will try to crawl some innocent webpages such as `year=2030&month=12`.

This is quite stupid.

How can I avoid such trap in Nutch? Writing many regex expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add regex patterns to `conf/regex-urlfilter.txt` to speficy rules to accept or reject urls.